# Emacs org-mode configuration

Tags: linux, emacs, org-mode

I'm trying to configure the `org-mode` in Emacs. I'd like to use the `org-capture` feature.

I don't know whether I misunderstood, but if I try to capture something with `C-c c` from a non `org`-file, it doesn't work.

**Question**

How could I configure `org-capture` to function from whatever filetype I'm working with?

**My `.emacs`**

```
;; --------- Org mode settings
;; ----- TODO sequence
(setq org-todo-keywords
       '((sequence "TODO(t)" "FEEDBACK(f)" "VERIFY(v)" "WAITING(w)" "|" "DONE(d)" "DELEGATED(l)")))
;; ----- Key sequences
(require 'org-install)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/oscar/Software/org-8.0.7/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/oscar/Software/org-8.0.7/contrib/lisp" t)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org$" . org-mode))
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
(define-key global-map "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(global-font-lock-mode 1)
(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-directory "~/Documents/Orgfiles/")
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
(setq org-capture-templates
    '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "~/Documents/Orgfiles/gtd.org" "Tasks")
       "* TODO %?\n %i\n %a")
      ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree "~/Documents/Orgfiles/journal.org")
       "* %?\nEntered on %U\n %i\n %a")))
```

Comment: I tested your config and it worked. It is strange that doesn't work on your side. Maybe you can provide more detailed how it not work.

Comment: @rwxrwxrwx If I'm programming in Python (`python-mode`) and I'd like to capture a task, It does not work! My question is (in other words): Is it supposed to work outside `org-mode`? I'd like it to do!

Comment: Try calling the function with M-x instead of with the keyboard shortcut to see if another shortcut is causing a conflict, or run C-h k and your shortcut to see what comes up.

Comment: What do you get when you type `C-h k C-c c` when in a non-org file.  Sounds like you've got another keybinding shadowing `org-capture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this will be helpful or not, but here are my settings:

```
(setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))
(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)

(setq org-capture-templates
      (quote (("t" "todo" entry (file (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))
               "* TODO %?\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("n" "note" entry (file (concat org-directory "/gtd.org"))
               "* %? :NOTE:\n%U\n%a\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              ("j" "Journal" entry (file+datetree (concat org-directory "/diary.org"))
               "* %?\n%U\n" :clock-in t :clock-resume t)
              )))
```

For me it works fine. Do you have the `org-directory` defined? Do you have the `.org` files there? I don't think `org-mode` creates the directories and files.

Comment: If I'm programming in Python (`python-mode`) and I'd like to capture a task, It does not work! My question is (in other words): Is it supposed to work outside `org-mode`? I'd like it to do!

Comment: For me it does work from any mode. Maybe try to install `org-mode` from `ELPA`? Make sure to install it when the session of `emacs` did not run **any** `org-mode` functions (http://orgmode.org/Changes.html)